# Two SQL queries returning odd results

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to run a query which gives latest arrears when provided with `admission_code`, but there is some logical error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fees_invoice_information AS fii
WHERE fii.admission_code = 12111
```

This SQL returns:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU8E7.png)

While when I want to get latest record from following query

```
SELECT
    MAX(fii.id),fii.*,
    sep.registration_code,
    sep.admission_code,
    fii.arrears,
    sep.is_enabled 
FROM 
    fees_invoice_information AS fii
JOIN 
    std_education_profile AS sep ON fii.admission_code = sep.admission_code 
WHERE 
    fii.`admission_code`  = 12111
```

I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U97MJ.png)

In which "arrears" column is not '0'

Comment: `sql quries` - that almost looked like `Squirrelies`

Comment: where's the php for this, since you did tag as such?

Comment: Rather than having us look at two different screenshots of your results and expected results, you should be typing that out in your question instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sometimes I wonder if we are not in the 90's still, not just from the code, pictures sometimes aswell...(with code I refer to `mysql_*` funcitons.. ).

Answer (score 1):

Move the `MAX` criteria to a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT fii.*,
       sep.registration_code,
       sep.admission_code,
       sep.is_enabled 
FROM fees_invoice_information AS fii
INNER JOIN std_education_profile AS sep
    ON fii.admission_code = sep.admission_code 
WHERE fii.admission_code = 12111 AND
      fii.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM fees_invoice_information)
```

Or you could use a `LIMIT 1` trick:

```
SELECT fii.*,
       sep.registration_code,
       sep.admission_code,
       sep.is_enabled 
FROM fees_invoice_information AS fii
INNER JOIN std_education_profile AS sep
    ON fii.admission_code = sep.admission_code 
WHERE fii.admission_code = 12111
ORDER BY fii.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note: This assumes that it makes logical sense to return only a single record based on the max ID.  If the join isn't one to one then you might want to return a *group* of records, or an aggregate of a group of records.